# Check for resources that are being loaded, but not used

Tags: optimization, httprequest, performance-testing, http-request

I remember there were a few sites out there previously that would check for unused CSS. I'm hoping there's something similar out there that will check for any resources loaded over HTTP that aren't used. For example, building a site with bootstrap or foundation would load several resources unnecessarily if you use a stock install. I'm looking for something similar for a legacy CMS that I manage where there are hundreds of pages but the code bloat is astounding. I guess I'm just hoping for a tool that will minimize the work I'll have to do. THanks.

Answer (score 0):

- [CSSLint.net](http://csslint.net/)
- [CSS Usage plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/)
- You could also generate a waterfall chart of the resources and then check what is being loaded. Using http://www.webpagetest.org/ is easy
- [Find unused css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650146/find-unused-css)